# Breaking down a raw transaction:

Tags: hash, raw-transaction, bitcoin-cli, createrawtransaction, raw

**Complete example:**

> 0100000001186f9f998a5aa6f048e51dd8419a14d8a0f1a8a2836dd734d2804fe65fa35779000000008b483045022100884d142d86652a3f47ba4746ec719bbfbd040a570b1deccbb6498c75c4ae24cb02204b9f039ff08df09cbe9f6addac960298cad530a863ea8f53982c09db8f6e381301410484ecc0d46f1918b30928fa0e4ed99f16a0fb4fde0735e7ade8416ab9fe423cc5412336376789d172787ec3457eee41c04f4938de5cc17b4a10fa336a8d752adfffffffff**02**60e31600000000001976a914ab68025513c3dbd2f7b92a94e0581f5d50f654e788acd0ef8000000000001976a9147f9b1a7fb68d60c536c2fd8aeaa53a8f3cc025a888ac00000000

---

**Breakdown:**

Version (4-byte):

**01000000**

---

Number of inputs (variable size but in this case it is 1-byte):

**01**

---

Previous transaction ID byte swapped (32-byte):

**186f9f998a5aa6f048e51dd8419a14d8a0f1a8a2836dd734d2804fe65fa35779**

---

prev_out_index (4-byte):

**00000000**

---

scriptSig length (variable size but in this case it is 2-byte which represents 139-bytes for the following scrtiptSig):

**8b**

---

scriptSig (variable size but in this case it’s 139-byte):

**483045022100884d142d86652a3f47ba4746ec719bbfbd040a570b1deccbb6498c75c4ae24cb02204b9f039ff08df09cbe9f6addac960298cad530a863ea8f53982c09db8f6e381301410484ecc0d46f1918b30928fa0e4ed99f16a0fb4fde0735e7ade8416ab9fe423cc5412336376789d172787ec3457eee41c04f4938de5cc17b4a10fa336a8d752adf**

---

Sequence number: (4-byte):

**ffffffff**

---

Don’t know what this is:

**02**

---

Value to send (8-byte byte-swapped):

**60e3160000000000**

---

Output 1 – Receiving address for amount above:

**19 76 a9 14ab68025513c3dbd2f7b92a94e0581f5d50f654e7 88 ac**

---

Value for change (8-byte byte-swapped)

**d0ef800000000000**

---

Output 2- Change address for amount above:

**19 76 a9 147f9b1a7fb68d60c536c2fd8aeaa53a8f3cc025a8 88 ac**

---

LockTime (4-byte):

**00000000**

---

**Question:**

The bit where I wrote `Don’t know what this is`, which has the value `02`.  I don't know what the purpose of that value is.  What's the purpose of that value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bolded byte in the following raw transaction is the number of outputs (two in this transaction):

> 0100000001186f9f998a5aa6f048e51dd8419a14d8a0f1a8a2836dd734d2804fe65fa35779000000008b483045022100884d142d86652a3f47ba4746ec719bbfbd040a570b1deccbb6498c75c4ae24cb02204b9f039ff08df09cbe9f6addac960298cad530a863ea8f53982c09db8f6e381301410484ecc0d46f1918b30928fa0e4ed99f16a0fb4fde0735e7ade8416ab9fe423cc5412336376789d172787ec3457eee41c04f4938de5cc17b4a10fa336a8d752adfffffffff**02**60e31600000000001976a914ab68025513c3dbd2f7b92a94e0581f5d50f654e788acd0ef8000000000001976a9147f9b1a7fb68d60c536c2fd8aeaa53a8f3cc025a888ac00000000

The Bitcoin.org Developer Documentation has an extended description of the [raw transaction format](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#raw-transaction-format) if you'd like more information.

Answer (score 1):

> Don’t know what this is:
>
> **02**

It's the number of outputs in the transaction.